# Suggest a book on spatial data structures

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, quadtree, octree

Please advice a book on spatial data structures. I'm interested in `Quadtrees and Octrees`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123694469) has good credentials.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Handbook of data structures and applications

[image]